# sitecore remove validation previous versions

Tags: validation, sitecore, sitecore7, multiple-versions, broken-links

After upgrading my project to the latest sitecore 7 items that were referencing some products got the links broken as the products had changed IDs. As expected sitecore shows an icon saying that we have broken links. So far so good and I fixed all the links on the latest version. However those items have more versions and the links on these versions are broken too and the icon still displays. 
Is it possible to remove validation just from old versions?
Do you suggest some other approach?

Thanks in advance

Notes:
I can't remove previous versions;
I can't set the same links for all the versions;

Comment: Were these referencing default Sitecore items, or your own items? I've just upgraded a very large project and there was no issues with the IDs being changed.

Comment: Own items, basically these products are loaded from a CRM. During this process they get a different ID.

Comment: Ahhh ok, that makes sense then! It would have been better if you could have stored the CRM id in the Sitecore item and then just updated the data rather than created new ones.

Comment: Yes its true. But that is something out of my control.

Comment: Can you use C# code or do you only have the Content Editor to work with?

Comment: How many products are we talking? Not aware of the Sitecore structure & how the CRM items are stored; this approach that might help:- Try storing the CRM items in a folder somewhere in sitecore. If you can create product items in Sitecore. Now make these Sitecore created products look into that location where you have stored your CRM products, fetch the relevant product from that list. There might be C# code involved in the customisation. Not knowing how your CRM product items are named or ided, but some pattern you will be able to find to match. And hopefully not worry if those ids change.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. In the end Sitecore provided a custom dll for this functionality. Cheers

Comment: You might want to write an answer (or maybe share the solution from what Sitecore support gave you) and mark _that_ as an answer. I remember running into similar issue before, and it would be nice to have a solution in case I run into it again :)